# Why can I only use the = assignment operator with the keyword var?

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

I've been studying about variables and I've realized that I can only use the "=" assignment operator together with the "var" keyword when I set a variable. So why can't I use other assignment operators instead, like:

```
var example = 5 + 3 //It'd display 8.
var example += 2 //It'd display SyntaxError
```

My theory is that the keyword var treats everything behind the = operator as a variable name and since we can't name a variable with arithmetic operators it shows an error. I'm not sure and I haven't found an answer on the web about it, that's why I came here.

Comment: The `=` in a `var` (or `let` or `const`) declaration statement is not quite the same as `=` in the context of an ordinary expression. The only way to assign an initial value to a declared variable is `=`, because that's what the language syntax insists upon, even if you are (needlessly) redeclaring a variable in a second `var` statement.

Comment: So there's no special reason to this occurs? I mean, does this happen because the syntax require that?

Comment: Yes, a `var` declaration is its own kind of statement, with its own syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Initializing a variable and assigning a value to it makes good sense:

```
var example = 5 + 3
```

But `x +=` is syntax sugar for `x = x +`. Initializing a variable *and referring to the value previously contained in it* doesn't make sense, because the variable hasn't been initialized before that line.

```
var example += 2
```

if it were even syntactically permitted, would basically mean

```
var example = example + 2
```

or

```
var valueToAssign = example + 2;
var example = valueToAssign;
```

which is nonsensical because `example` hasn't been initialized yet - referencing a nonexistent variable while in the process of creating the `valueToAssign` would not make sense. Hence, it is forbidden by the syntax.

For `var` (and not `let` and `const`), it's technically possible to reference a variable before it's assigned to in the same scope, but doing so deliberately and explicitly with `+=` (or any of the other similar operators) just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I got what you said, but I made some experimental exercises before sending this topic and I haven't put it there. So, you said that I can't declare a variable with the self assignment operator 'cause it haven't been declared before. But why this is possible: `var a = 5;  var a = a + 5;` and this isn't possible: `var a = 5; var a += 3;` since they're "almost the same"?

Comment: @ネイサン that's simply the way the language syntax is defined. "Why?" questions like that ultimately have to do with decisions made by the people who designed and maintain the language specification. It's like asking "why is water so wet?".